# pragmatic way to compute/ search/ match MSBs operation

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, arithmetic

consider integers represented as base 2 (strings). define a relation called "*n*-msb matching" that is true when the 1<sup>st</sup> *n* msbs (MSB is "most significant bits") match (of two integers). what is a *pragmatic* way of searching/ computing the following?

> given *n<sub>2</sub>,* find *x, n* such that *n·3<sup>x</sup>* is "many msb matching" (with *n<sub>2</sub>*).

note am not necessarily looking for *efficient*. a nice/ ideal answer would also analyze the complexity (ie # of possible solutions, hardness of finding etc)

background: naturally arises in [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) [study](https://vzn1.wordpress.com/2015/06/08/startling-collatz-plateau/).

Comment: 1. What have you tried?  What data structures have you considered?  A hash table or trie seem like obvious candidates....  2. If you're not looking for efficient then what *are* you looking for?  It's trivial to find a solution if you don't care about efficiency.  What's the difference between complexity vs efficiency?  I can't understand the question.

Comment: What is "many msb matching"? What is the minimum value of many?

Comment: So for a given $k$, two bit strings $a$ and $b$ are *$k$-matched* if the first $k$ most significant bits of $a$ and $b$ are equal, is that correct? I'm not understanding the question completely though, but maybe I am not trying hard enough :-S